# All checkboxes are checked in edit mode

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a create/edit form

```
@if(isset($vendor))
  {{ Form::model($vendor,array('route' => 'vendor-edit'))}}
@else
  {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'vendor-post'))}}
```

within this form I have a checkboxes listed out

```
    @foreach ($locations as $location)
      <div style='display:none' class="{{$location['state']['state']}}">
            {{Form::checkbox('city[]',$location['id'])}}{{$location['city']}}
      </div>
    @endforeach
```

I am noticing in edit mode everything is being checked. It seems like it is having trouble with the name being 'city[]'.

Answer (score 0):

Your code means that for each location, if `$location->city` has any value, the checkbox named `city[]` should be marked as checked (since any non-null or non-zero value in `city` will evaluate as `true`).

Either change the name of the checkbox from `city[]` to the field holding the `true`/`false` value in `locations` that should determine the state of the checkbox; or, change the name from `city[]` to something else (so the model form binding doesn't try to set it based on `$location->city`) and set the `checked` value by setting the 3rd parameter of `Form::checkbox` to `true`/`false` based on the value of some other field:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('thecity[]', $location->id, $location->other_field > 0 ) }}
```